# Which encryption tool is creating file extension .$#!

Tags: windows, file, encryption, installation

I want to ask you whether you know which encryption tool is creating file extension $#! I encrypted few years ago some files which I need now, but I do not know which tool I used :-( Unfortunatelly google did not help. Therefore I am here.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Cryptext. (as seen [here](http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=%5E%5B%5EA-Z0-9%5D) and [here](http://www.spywarepoint.com/does-one-show-extension-cryptext-under-windows-xppro-t42057.html))